# Remove constraints in sequelize migration

Tags: javascript, sql, constraints, sequelize.js

I'm adding a `unique` constraint in a migration via the [migrations.changeColumn](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/#changecolumntablename-attributename-datatypeoroptions) function.

Adding the constraint works, but since you need to provide a “backwards migration“, removing it the same way does not. It doesn't give any errors when migrating backwards, but again applying the forward migration results in `Possibly unhandled SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "myAttribute_unique_idx" already exists`.

(The used database is postgres)

```
module.exports = {
  up: function (migration, DataTypes, done) {
    migration.changeColumn(
      'Users',
      'myAttribute',
      {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true                 // ADDING constraint works
      }
    ).done(done);
  },

  down: function (migration, DataTypes, done) {
    migration.changeColumn(
      'Users',
      'myAttribute',
      {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: false                // REMOVING does not
      }
    ).done(done);
  }
};
```

I also tried using [removeIndex](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/#removeindextablename-indexnameorattributes)

```
migration.removeIndex('Users', 'myAttribute_unique_idx').done(done);
```

But it gives the following error when reverting the migration:

```
Possibly unhandled SequelizeDatabaseError: cannot drop index "myAttribute_unique_idx" because constraint myAttribute_unique_idx on table "Users" requires it
```

Comment: were you able to do it without using sequelize.query.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

As of 2017 with Sequelize 4.4.2, we can remove constraints with queryInterface API:

`queryInterface.removeConstraint(tableName, constraintName)`

Documentation is [here](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-removeConstraint).

Comment: Updated documentation [here](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-removeConstraint)

Comment: doesn't work for me, throws error: can't find constraint with particular name. Even though constraint do exist and below raw query removed it well

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately sequelize doesn't have a builtin migration method to remove constraint. That is why before removing key you need to make a raw query.

```
down: function (migration, DataTypes) {
  migration.sequelize.query(
    'ALTER TABLE Users DROP CONSTRAINT myAttribute_unique_idx;'
  );
  migration.removeIndex('Users', 'myAttribute_unique_idx');

  return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The docs aren't very clear on this limitation.

Comment: Yeah, the docs imply you can with ```references: null```, but that does not work. This doubly sucks because I cannot find a way to name my constrains, which means my migrations are tightly coupled to a particular version of sequelize. Yuck!

Comment: Make sure to put the table name in the raw query in double qoutes if the name is not lowercase:
`'ALTER TABLE "Users" DROP CONSTRAINT myAttribute_unique_idx;'`

Answer (score 11):

Sequelize has `removeConstraint()` method if you want to remove the constraint.
So you can have use something like this:

`return queryInterface.removeConstraint('users', 'users_userId_key', {})`

where `users` is my Table Name and `users_userId_key` is index or constraint name which is generally of the form `attributename_unique_key` if you have unique constraint which you wanna remove(say).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to remove the index you should use:

```
down: function (migration, DataTypes) {
    return migration.removeIndex('Users', 'myAttribute_unique_idx');
}
```

The return is used to use promise style instead of callbacks. This is recommended by sequelize.

It would also be good to handle the creation of the index on your own as descripted here:
http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/migrations/#addindextablename-attributes-options

Answer (score 0):

Just simply do this:

```js
 await queryInterface.removeConstraint("Users","myAttribute" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add both an **up** and a **down** migration so `removeConstraint` does not error when moving up and down the migrations.

Up and down migration:

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    //remove constraint
    queryInterface.removeConstraint("projects", "projects_action_id_fkey");
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    //re-add a reference example with a raw query
    queryInterface.sequelize.query(
    `
      ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.action_executions
      ADD CONSTRAINT projects_action_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (action_id)
      REFERENCES public.actions (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION
      ON DELETE NO ACTION;
    `
    );
  }
};
```